# MFP 8 Push Notification to Particular USER ID

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Trying to send Push Notification based on DEVICE_ID, In MFP 8 Console, My device ID is showing under DEVICES section but if i try to send notification, Console throws error as **"An error occurred while the notification was sent. Internal server error. No devices found."**

Scope - push.mobileclient
Initialize, isPushSupported and then RegisterDevice is triggered and in logs, it shown the token as well. how to resolve ?

Answer (score 0):

Device registration showing up in the Devices console does not mean that push registration is successful. Even if push registration is complete, it will depend entirely on the application logic that there is a user identity associated with the subscription.

When you attempt to send notification by userid and it says "No devices found", this means that there are no subscriptions against this userid. It is possible there is no subscription at all , or the subscriptions have been made against a different user - or even anonymous user.

Use [get push registrations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_device_registrations_get.html) and [get push subscriptions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_device_subscriptions_get.html) REST calls to verify your current registration and subscription. If these are with anonymous user identity verify your scope -> security check mapping and your application logic.

Comment: am using UserLogin SecurityCheck again push.mobileclient scope and getting Success in challenge handler also, if SecurityCheck can add the UserId and Display name, then why we need REGISTERDEVICE function separately for PUSH ?

Comment: Because Push is a separate component.